# Why is Facebook login redirecting me to Zoho?

Tags: facebook, zoho

I was using Facebook Connect to log into a site, but I was redirected to Zoho account management.

I was asked to either

1. Create a private portal or
2. Create a community forum.

I wasn't sure how to respond. This has happened to me before. Why am I being redirected?

Comment: What router do you have? It may be related to this question: http://superuser.com/a/394731/100787

Comment: OS?, Browser?, installed AV?

Comment: You know, the site you are signing in can also be coded to redirect you anywhere once Facebook is connected. I don't see any reason but possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like some malware, more than likely your proxy settings got turned on and you're being redirected to another site. Not sure what browser you are using but go into the Internet properties and check to ensure the proxy server doesnt have anything weird in it.

To check the proxy on Firefox go to PREFERENCES >> ADVANCED >> NETWORK >> SETTINGS >> Make sure no proxy is set.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the site you used to login uses Zoho Discussions, a community portal. But you may have already used Facebook connect for another Zoho account of yours (CRM/ Mail/ Wiki/ Projects), hence you were redirected to the Zoho account management portal, since Zoho uses SSO.

Instead of sign up, choose "I have an account" and use Facebook Connect to login to the site and you should be connected to the site without any issues.